# JSON decode in PHP from a url

Tags: php, json

Hello i am new with Json  in php. I have a web service  that gives me data in json format.
I take this  data making decode put when i try to use this data i cant

Here is my code:

```
 $url = "http://www.webinsurer.gr/....;

    $json = json_decode(@file_get_contents($url), true);
```

and if i make debug i see the data i take :

```
[file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\development.insurancemarket.gr\mvc\protected\models\Ratingsmail.php
[line] => 18
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [POL_EXPIREDATE] => 2014-05-19 12:00:00
                [INCO_IWCODE] => 41
                [INCO_DESC] => MAPFRE ASISTENCIA
                [PACK_IWCODE] => 0
                [PACK_DESC] => 
                [OFFERCODE] => 
                [PAYMENTCODE] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (.....
```

But i dont  now how to use that data. when i try this :

```
$b= $json->{1}->{'INCO_IWCODE'};

    Debug::debuger($b);
```

the result is nothing

what is wrong? sorry for long post.

Comment: show us   console.log($json), it will output to the firebug/developer tools console (f12 in any browser)

Comment: "*if I make debug*" with what code? Is this `print_r($json)`? If so you need to use `$json['data'][0]['INCO_IWCODE']`.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672905/json-decode-in-php-from-a-url/23672982#23672982)

Comment: @BartłomiejWach What? You cannot debug PHP variables on a javascript console.

Comment: remove ", true" from your json decode line.

Comment: @EJTH my bad, unused to parsing json in php ;) I think the question was answered in one of the answers below

Comment: No its not yet. i am taking null data in the debug yet. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the second argument on json_decode to true, you are actively asking for the data to be returned in an associative array and not objects. Thats why your code didn't work.

Comment: i removed the true  and again in the debug the data was empty

Comment: @theodosis `$json->data[1]->INCO_IWCODE` - you are using `{...}` which is wrong and has a different meaning in PHP

Comment: Also what Dan said :-) To elaborate: {...} is for dynamic referencing, eg. if the variable you want depends on a computed result, or when the variable has a naming which is incompatible with PHP syntax: `$obj->{$myvar}` or `$obj->{'invalid-variable-name'}` are examples of valid uses. It does not work with arrays of any kind, only objects.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/GXZcckcT)**

You are converting json to associative array. You need to use;

```
$b = $json["data"][1]["INCO_IWCODE"];
```

Comment: its not working the result is :
Array
(
    [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\development.insurancemarket.gr\mvc\protected\models\Ratingsmail.php
    [line] => 30
    [data] => 
)

Comment: @user3438570 it is not working with what? Your formatting a bit hard to read. Please see my demo in answer

Comment: I took your code but again in the debug  the data was empty. i dont now why.

Answer (score 0):

$a = $json[0]->INCO_IWCODE;

That worked for my guys. thanks you all!!!